# Run PowerShell if statement between business hours

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to run a conditional statement based on if it's business hours or not. Business hours for us are 08:00 to 17:00. I have the script below, but it's not working.

I'm trying to compare `(Get-Date).tostring('%H')` to the hour number.

I have also tried `((Get-Date).hour -ge 17)` and it still failed.

Any thoughts?

```
while ($loop -eq 1) {

Write-Host "Running"

    # Get last write timestamp
    $lastwrite = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $source -Name LastWriteTime).lastwritetime

    if ( ((Get-Date).tostring('%H') -le "8" ) -and ( (Get-Date).tostring('%H') -ge "17" ) ) {
        # Do nothing, it is outside of the time window
        Write-Host "Nothing to do, outside of business hours"
    } elseif (($lastwrite -le (Get-Date).addMinutes(-$ageMinutes)) -and ((Get-Date).tostring('%H') -ge "8" -and (Get-Date).tostring('%H') -le "17")) {
        # If it's older than $ageMinutes variable above, send an email
        notify
        $oldTimestampFound = 1
        # Sleep for 4 minutes to not flood inboxes (5 minute sleep total with the while loop)
        Write-Host "Alert sent. Sleeping for 4 minutes..."
        Start-Sleep -s 300
    } elseif (($lastwrite -ge (Get-Date).addMinutes(-$ageMinutes)) -and ($oldTimestampFound -eq 1)) {
        $oldTimestampFound = 0
        Write-Host "All clear"
        notifyAllClear
    }

    Write-Host "Sleeping for 60 seconds..."
    Start-Sleep -s 60

}
```

I put those `Write-Hosts` in there to try and debug, but my output is

```
Running
Sleeping for 60 seconds...
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why don't you just set it up to run in the task scheduler over and over during business hours.  That way too if the script crashes it will automatically start after the next sleep cycle.

Comment: Good question and one that I've pondered. This script is temporary and wanted to just get something going within the script, and just keep it running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're formatting the Get-Date wrong, use the `-Format HH` option for Get-Date Personally I'd set it once as an integer for easy comparisons like this:

```
[int]$hour = get-date -format HH
If($hour -lt 8 -or $hour -gt 17){ <do nothing> }
Else{
    If($lastwrite -le (Get-Date).addMinutes(-$ageMinutes)){ <send email, set oldTimeStampFound flag, and sleep> }
    Else{
        <Clear oldTimeStampFound flag>
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that -and might need to be an -or.

Comment: @mjolinor Good catch, thanks for bringing it to my attention! I've fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Works great, and you cleaned up my "brain dump" mess of code. Thanks!

Comment: Or just use (Get-Date).Hour.

Comment: I needed quite oposit, then `-and` should be used. `# Do not run script during the night - from 1 till 6. [int]$hour = get-date -format HH If ($hour -ge 1 -and $hour -le 6) { Exit } Else { <run rest of the script code>}`